# Splitting a string into sets of words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for string **"Occupational Health and Safety"**. I want the first word to be split in $1 and the rest of the string in $2. So **"Occupational"** in one string and **"Health and Safety"** in the other string. Can you please help me out?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I tried var matches = htm.split(/(\w)(\s)/);

Comment: I want it in javascript.

Comment: Can your string contain newlines?

Answer (score 5):

```
(\S+)\s+(.*)
```

puts the first non-whitespace string into `$1` and the rest after the splitting whitespace into `$2`.

```
match = subject.match(/(\S+)\s+(.*)/);
if (match != null) {
    // first word: match[1]
    // rest of string: match[2]
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

If your string can contain newlines, you need (since you're using JavaScript):

```
(\S+)\s+([\s\S]*)
```

Comment: The anchors are really not necessary in this case. :-) Heck, if you take out the anchors, you can even remove the `\s*` from the front.

Comment: If I want it in $0 how can I do that with this regex ?

Comment: Why? But OK, that could be done with lookahead: `\S+(?=\s+(.*)$)`.

Comment: Edit: Improved the regex by making the first non-whitespace string mandatory. Now the leading `\s*` can be dropped.